# How can I get the text from a simple HTML tag using Selenium RC?

Tags: selenium, junit, selenium-rc

How can I get the text from a simple html tag

```
<h2>ABCDEF</h2>
```

using Selenium RC?

I want to match the exact text. If I use `isTextPresent()` it returns true even if I put `selenium.isTextPresent("ABC")`.

This is in a HTML tag `<h2>`.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but do you have to use RC or can you use WebDriver? From the Selenium home page, "Selenium WebDriver is the successor of Selenium Remote Control which has been officially deprecated..." http://docs.seleniumhq.org/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Then you need to do the following

```
strText = selenium.getText("//h2")

if strText.equals("ABCDEF")
     System.out.println("TextMatch")
else
     System.out.println("Text Mismatch")
```

Comment: Since the OP tagged the post with [tag:junit], more appropriate would be just: `assertEquals("Text Mismatch", "ABCDEF", selenium.getText("//h2"))`